# How do I fix this; 'Found array with dim 4. RandomForestClassifier expected <= 2'?

Tags: python, image, dataset

I am trying to use random forest on an image dataset and I keep getting the above error every time I run this code - I am new to working with image datasets and am not sure how to fix this:

```
train_images = np.array(train_images)
train_lables = np.array(train_labels)

test_images = []
test_labels = []

for directory_path in glob.glob("Desktop/brains/validation/*"):
    fruit_label = directory_path.split("\\")[-1]
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*jpg")):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (SIZE<SIZE))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    test_images,append(img)
    test_labels.append(fruit_label)

test_images = np.array(test_images)
test_labels = np.array(test_labels)

from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(test_labels)
test_labels_encoded = le.transform(test_labels)
le.fit(train_labels)
train_labels_encoded = le.transform(train_labels)
```

x_train, y_train,x_test,y_test = train_images, train_labels_encoded, test_images,test_labels_encoded

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

random_forest = RandomForestClassifier(oob_score=True)
model_rm = random_forest.fit(x_train, y_train)